# PDO errorinfo with user which has no privilege

Tags: mysql, pdo

I set on mysql user only SELECT privilege

Then, When I run `UPDATE ...` query

```
$sth = $db->prepare( $update_sql );

if (!$sth) {
    echo "fail";
}
else {
    echo "Ok";
}
```

Printed `Ok`, though in table nothing updated.

Question: Why printed `Ok` and not `fail` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to `execute` the query you've prepared:

```
$sth->execute();
```

The prepared statement itself does not do anything on the database. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) provides more specifics.

Remember the `exceute` call is when you can bind your [SQL placeholder values](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 1):

...because you didn't *execute* the statement - you only *prepared* it.

```
function try_to_run($sql, $db)
{
   $sth = $db->prepare( $update_sql );
   if (false===$sth) return false;
   $r=$sth->execute();
   return $r;
}

if (false===try_to_run($sql, $db)) {
   echo "fail";
} else {
   echo "Ok";
}
```

Comment: Why the `if (false===$sth)` idiom? Just how `false` do you need something to be?

Comment: A successful query can return zero rows. While this is semantically not an issue for the execute method (compared with the exec method) I still consider it good practice.

Comment: It does lead to an awkward double-negative in the `else`, though.